# connecting to database SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] on new server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have recently changed server and uploaded my database to the server, for the live website i made no changes to my env and everything works the same. But in my php storm development i have had to change the ip(db host) and despite the username and password being the same i am getting an error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'connect'@'xxxxxx' (using password: YES)
```

I have cleared config and cache and tried launching php artisan again but get the same issue. i have even brought in the env from the server(live website) and changed the DB Host to match the IP of the server but then the error occurs. Does anyone know how i fix this error, could it be an issue with the fact the database was imported from another server?

Comment: Cross check your database username/password ?

Comment: both correct as they are the same on the live website. the issue seems to be when i change the host from localhost to the server ip

Comment: did you try to keep it as `localhost` ?

Comment: I am trying to connect to the database from my development server not from the host server of the database so that will not work.